# Disposing of Bitmaps used in background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap, dispose, emgucv

I need to know how to properly dispose of Bitmaps so that I don't have a memory leak.
I am grabbing video in a BackgroundWorker and assigning it to a PictureBox as such:

```
private void bwVideo_ReadCamera(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap temp = null;
  while (true)
  {
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = logitec.QueryFrame();
    if (temp != null)
      temp.Dispose();
    temp = frame.ToBitmap();
    pictureBox2.Image = temp;
   }
}
```

The problem is that I still get a "Out of Memory Exception" with this code.  I have tried freeing the pictureBox2.Image variable by using a BackgroundWorker ReportProgress and waiting in the above code for the dispose to finish (you need to be synched with the gui to call dispose on the PictureBox image).  I have also tried to use the "Bitmap" property of the Image class which shares data between the Image and Bitmap.

So my questions is, in this situation, what is the proper way to dispose of my image?

Comment: where is the Out of Memory Exception thrown?

Comment: Where is frame declared?  What type is frame?  Does frame need to be disposed?

Comment: Sorry, frame declaration is now shown.  The out of Memory exception is thrown on the frame.ToBitmap();

Comment: Wow that worked remarkably well.  If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.  I had assumed because I am using the Image data elsewhere that I could not dispose it or wrap it in a using statement so I hadn't even tried.  Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do; only the last value assigned to `pictureBox2.Image` should matter, so why are you writing the rest of them?  If you want to update the image on the display while the loop is running, you should get the device context from `pictureBox2` and draw it directly.  If you draw the image yourself, you can dispose it (other than the very last one) as soon as it's drawn.

Comment: Moved comment to an answer.

Comment: @supercat: I am assigning it to the other one (not multiple) in order to dispose it.  If I try to dispose imagebox2.Image it crashes the paint.  Disposing the Image variable is the way to go, though your idea sounds like it would work, albeit more complicated, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have a using statement for your `Image<Bgr, Byte>` declaration. See [the documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Automatic_Garbage_Collection).

Comment: Perfect.  As my code was actually a bit more complicated than the snippet I posted I simply called the Image.Dispose() method after assigning to the PictureBox.  I should have realized that the assignment copies the data over and it is then fine to release the Bitmap.